# Cocoa - Avoid Menu modality

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

As an example, this can be observed if a progress indicator is running and main menu is pulled down. What is the best way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally, apps did continue while menus were open. It was changed later in OS X's history — I want to say 10.3. The reason things appear to "stop" is that, when a menu is open, the app runs in NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode. So run loop sources have to be added for that mode if you want them to continue when a menu is open.